# How to render partial only on production build?

Tags: middleman, slim-lang

I'm injecting Google Analytics script with partial inside layout. Something like that:

```
...
= partial "analytics"
...
```

And *analytics.slim* including this:

```
javascript:
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']...
```

Obvious solution is:

```
- if environment == 'production'
  = partial 'analytics'
```

But is doesn't work. Is it possible implement this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
...
- if build?
  = partial 'analytics'
...
```